# Warning: Prop minSize is deprecated and will be removed in the next major release

Tags: reactjs

I am using React.js and I've noticed I get the following warning:

```
Prop minSize is deprecated and will be removed in the next major release.
```

I looked around a bit and I couldn't find anyplace i am using minSize, also I didn't find anything in google about this warning, does anyone know what makes the warning pop?

Comment: Please add details about the "minSize". Which component is the prop being passed to?

Comment: @AnmolMahatpurkar has a point. The warning is not related to React it self, but probably to a package you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This warning comes from [react-dropzone](https://github.com/okonet/react-dropzone) package.

Exactly from here:
https://github.com/okonet/react-dropzone/blob/master/src/index.js#L425

```
minSize: deprecate(
  React.PropTypes.number,
  'Prop minSize is deprecated and will be removed in the next major release'
)
```